# Changing a macro via another macro in excel VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, cell

basically i want to change a macro via another macro.

The first macro looks like this :

```
Sub MacroLundi()

    Dim students As Variant
    Dim student As Variant
    Dim mySheet As Worksheet
    Set mySheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Lundi")
    students = Array("Armando", "Mathéo", "Djebril", "Anase", "Thibo_M")

    ' Loop through the students and update their schedules
    For Each student In students
        ' Emploi du temps Professionel 1
        If InStr(mySheet.Range("C6").Value, student) > 0 Then Workbooks("EdtEleve.ods").Sheets(student).Range("B11").Value = mySheet.Range("C5").Value
        If InStr(mySheet.Range("C8").Value, student) > 0 Then Workbooks("EdtEleve.ods").Sheets(student).Range("B12").Value = mySheet.Range("C7").Value
        If InStr(mySheet.Range("C10").Value, student) > 0 Then Workbooks("EdtEleve.ods").Sheets(student).Range("B13").Value = mySheet.Range("C9").Value
        If InStr(mySheet.Range("C13").Value, student) > 0 Then Workbooks("EdtEleve.ods").Sheets(student).Range("B15").Value = mySheet.Range("C12").Value
        If InStr(mySheet.Range("C15").Value, student) > 0 Then Workbooks("EdtEleve.ods").Sheets(student).Range("B16").Value = mySheet.Range("C14").Value
        If InStr(mySheet.Range("C17").Value, student) > 0 Then Workbooks("EdtEleve.ods").Sheets(student).Range("B17").Value = mySheet.Range("C16").Value
        If InStr(mySheet.Range("C19").Value, student) > 0 Then Workbooks("EdtEleve.ods").Sheets(student).Range("B18").Value = mySheet.Range("C18").Value
```

I want to then change the array students via the other macro. The other macro would use a simple excell cell from an excel sheet and it would change the array.

I tried with this but it doesnt not work :

```
Sub ListeEleve()


    Dim students As Variant
    Set mySheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ListeEleve")
    students = Split(Range("A1").Value, ",")
    
    
    MacroLundi students
    

End Sub

Sub MacroLundi(ByVal students As Variant)


    Dim i As Integer
    For i = LBound(students) To UBound(students)
        students(i) = Trim(students(i))
    Next i

End Sub
```

The "A1" cell contains : "Alexandre", "Mathéo"

If you have any advice or know why it does not work lemme known please ;)

Comment: `Sub MacroLundi(ByRef students As Variant)`

Comment: You need to read the manual so that you understand two things,  The difference between passing parameters byVal and ByRef.  The difference between a sub and a function.

Comment: There can be two approaches, I think: 1. Simpler: To declare `Public students As Variant` on top of a standard module, delete the declaration from `MacroLundi` code and use a **UDF Function** to load the array. 2. Search the `MacroLundi` code, find the code line starting with "students = Array("" and replace it with the new built array (build in a different way against the first suggested method).

Answer (score 0):

I suggested something in a comment, but you have not been moved...

Please, try the next scenario (the first in my comment):

1. Delete `Dim students As Variant` declaration from `MacroLundi` procedure and declare it on top of a standard module (in the declarations area) as:

```
  Public students As Variant
```

2. Replace the next part of existing code:

```
     students = Array("Armando", "Mathéo", "Djebril", "Anase", "Thibo_M")
```

with:

```
    If Not IsArray(students) Then 'first time when run the code:
         students = Array("Armando", "Mathéo", "Djebril", "Anase", "Thibo_M")
    End If
```

3. Copy the next Function in the same standard module:

```
Function updateStudents(rngStudents As Range) As String
    rngStudents.Replace " ", "" 'replace any space to let only comma as separator
    students = Split(rngStudents.Value, ",")
    updateStudents = Join(students, " ") 'return the joined obtained array
End Function
```

4. Call it from the sheet (as UDF):

```
  =updateStudents(A1)
```

But the content of "A1" cell **should not be  "Alexandre", "Mathéo"**! It must be something like  **Alexandre,Mathéo, Anase , Jean**. The spaces after or before the comma are mistakes able to be corrected by the above function. The ideal string should not contain any space.

Now, start playing with `updateStudents` UDF function/formula for different cells and run `MacroLundi`. Each time you run it will process the students from the array recently created by the UDF Function by splitting the respective cell argument...